# Find the summation of given expression: $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3\binom nk$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to solve the following question which is Ex3 from Arthur Engel, Problem Solving strategies. Here is the question: $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 {n \choose k}$ and asks to find the sum. I am sincerely having a hard time trying to figure out how to solve it and get $n^2 (n+3)(2)^{n-3}$. I would really appreciate if someone could show the step-by-step process. Thank you!

Comment: How about finding $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3\binom{n}k x^k$?

Comment: I am bad with combinatorics and that is why asked how to solve the above. I am trying to understand what techniques one uses and what knowledge is required to solve it.

Comment: Well, my strategy would be to find $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3\binom{n}k x^k$ and then put $x=1$ into it. If you can't see how to do that sum, then think about $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\binom{n}k x^k$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown And how would you suggest they compute that polynomial? I don't think you've made things easier from their perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k^3=k(k-1)(k-2)+ak(k-1)+ bk$

$\implies k=1,b=1$

$k=2,2^3=2a+2b\iff a=3$

Now for $k>2, $ $$k(k-1)(k-2)\binom nk=n(n-1)(n-2)\binom{n-3}{k-3}$$

Similarly $k\binom nk=?$

$k(k-1)\binom nk=?$

Finally use $(a+b)^m=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom mra^{m-r}b^r$

Set $a=b=1, m=n-3,n-2,n-1$

Comment: In fact coefficients in $k^3=ak(k-1)(k-2)+bk(k-1)+ ck$ are stirling numbers of the 2nd kind ; this remark is of little importance here for an exponent $3$ but be valuable for an exponent, sy, $10$...

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @LordSharktheUnknown's hint (since a duplicate of this question was recently posted), apply $x\frac{d}{dx}$ thrice to $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n$. First,$$\sum_k\binom{n}{k}kx^k=nx(1+x)^{n-1}=n(1+x)^n-n(1+x)^{n-1}.$$Second,$$\begin{align}\sum_k\binom{n}{k}k^2x^k&=n^2x(1+x)^{n-1}-n(n-1)x(1+x)^{n-2}\\&=n^2(1+x)^n-(2n^2-n)(1+x)^{n-1}+n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2}.\end{align}$$Third,$$\sum_k\binom{n}{k}k^3x^k=n^3x(1+x)^{n-1}-(2n^2-n)(n-1)x(1+x)^{n-2}+n(n-1)(n-2)x(1+x)^{n-3}.$$The case $x=1$ simplifies to $\sum_k\binom{n}{k}k^3=n^2(n+3)2^{n-3}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}k^{3}}&=3!\binom{n}{3}\sum_{k=3}^{n}{\binom{n-3}{k-3}}+6\binom{n}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n}{\binom{n-2}{k-2}}+\binom{n}{1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\\
\\
&=2^{n-3}\left(n^{3}-3n^{2}+2n\right)+3\ 2^{n-2}\left(n^{2}-n\right)+2^{4}n\\
\\
&=2^{n-3}\left(n^{3}+3n^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

LHS: choosing $k$ engineers from $n$ people then choosing production, maintenance, and research manager from them. One person can hold many title.

RHS: choosing production, maintenance, and research manager from $n$ people, then choose engineers from the remaining people to make $k$ total of engineers and managers.

Comment: Could you please help me explain the RHS in more details ?

Comment: @TungNguyen from left to right: three different people where each holds one managerial position, two different people where one of them holds one managerial position while the other holds the other two positions simultaneously, and last there is only one people who holds all three positions at the same time.

Comment: I got your your idea. But there is one thing I want to confirm is the coefficient "6" in the second term. Is it the permutation of the positions for 2 people, which is 3! ?

Comment: @TungNguyen you choose $2$ out of $3$ positions to be held simultaneously, that's $\binom{3}{2}=3$. Then you select $1$ of the $2$ people to hold the double position, that's $\binom{2}{1}=2$. So $3\cdot 2 = 6$.

Comment: Okie, I understand everything perfectly. Your idea is so direct and interesting. It does not require any complicative computation. Thank you a lot !

Comment: @TungNguyen that's the beauty of Combinatorial Proof :)

Comment: Do you have any sums that can perform by similar way ? I am very interested in looking at it.

Comment: @TungNguyen you can check some answers / questions I posted in this field: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a751970%20%5bcombinatorial-proofs%5d&searchOn=3

Comment: Wow, that's a lot. I will ask you if I have any confusion in these posts. =)))